# Can dark mode be enabled in dba.se?

Tags: support, feature-request

It it not possible to set dark mode in dba? In stackoverflow, it is possible.

Please enable it!
I have an eye cataract and the white mode hurts my eyes!

Comment: I would love dark mode.   I really hope StackOverflow (the company) makes this happen network-wide.  For now, you can use https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-exchange-dark-mode via Tampermonkey to enable dark mode.

Answer (score 4):

Not yet.

Currently, Dark Mode is available on the Stack Overflow sites only. More details can be found in [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits). At the moment, it isn't clear if, how, or when it will be rolled out to other sites in the network:

> #### Future releases
>
> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our [styles] easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.